# Is there a way of disabling panning on tablets - website?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I have setup the following css to stop middle mouse panning on computers:

```
overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x: hidden;
```

However, I can still pan around on my tablet by flicking my finger on the screen... is there a way of disabling this as well?

Thanks.

Comment: You'd also have to disable pinch-zoom which is usually not a good idea...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to your head

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

This stops the user from being able to pinch and zoom so should resolve your issue. Please use with caution though, not everybody likes having this functionality disabled!